# change the color of whole row on checkbox checked angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, row, panel

how can i make the whole row clickable and also when how to change the row color when i click the checkbox?

**here is my html file**

```
<section class="others">
<div class="sub-header">Others</div>
<p class="text-center" *ngIf="otherTests.length === 0">No Tests Available</p>
<app-custom-accordion [closeOthers]="true">
<ngb-panel [disabled]="true" *ngFor="let testPanel of otherTests" id=". {{testPanel.Id}}" [title]="testPanel.Name">
  <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
    <div class="action-items">
      <span class="material-icons fav" [class.favorited]="testPanel.Favorite" (click)="onFavoriteClick(testPanel)"></span>
      <span class="icon-set" [ngClass]="{'same-day-2x': isSameDay(testPanel.Code), 'next-day-2x': isNextDay(testPanel.Code)}"></span>
      <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" [name]="testPanel.Id + '-' + testPanel.Moniker" [ngModel]="panelIds.indexOf(testPanel.Id) > -1"
        (ngModelChange)="onPanelCheckboxUpdate($event, testPanel)" [id]="testPanel.Id + '-' + testPanel.Moniker">
        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</ngb-panel>
```

**here is my Ts file for checkbox change**

```
onPanelCheckboxUpdate($event: boolean, panel: TestOrderPanel) {
let testPanelIds = panel.Tests.map(test => test.Id);
// Wipe any duplicates
this.panelIds = this.panelIds.filter(
  panelId => panel.Id !== panelId && testPanelIds.indexOf(panelId) === -1
);
this.selectedPanels = this.selectedPanels.filter(
  selectedPanel =>
    panel.Id !== selectedPanel.Id &&
    testPanelIds.indexOf(selectedPanel.Id) === -1
);

if ($event) {
  this.panelIds.push(panel.Id);
  this.selectedPanels.push(panel);
   }
  this.updateSession();
}
```

**this is my app-custom-accordion component**

```
 <div class="card">
 <ng-template ngFor let-panel [ngForOf]="panels">
<div role="tab" id="{{panel.id}}-header" [class]="'card-header ' + 
 (panel.type ? 'card-' + panel.type: type ? 'card-' + type : '')"
  [class.active]="isOpen(panel.id)">
  <a href (click)="!!toggle(panel.id)" [attr.tabindex]=" . 
 (panel.disabled 
  ? '-1' : null)" [attr.aria-expanded]="isOpen(panel.id)"
    [attr.aria-controls]="(isOpen(panel.id) ? panel.id : null)" 
 [attr.aria-disabled]="panel.disabled">{{panel.title}}</a>
  <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="panel.titleTpl?.templateRef"></ng- 
  template>
  <!-- expansion arrows -->
  <div *ngIf="arrowExpand" (click)="toggle(panel.id)" [attr.aria- 
  expanded]="isOpen(panel.id)">
    <span class="material-icons expand"></span>
  </div>

 </div>
 <div id="{{panel.id}}" role="tabpanel" [attr.aria-labelledby]="panel.id + '-header'" class="card-block" *ngIf="isOpen(panel.id) && panel.contentTpl">
  <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="panel.contentTpl?.templateRef"></ng-template>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </div>
```

how to change the color of whole row when click on checkbox 
like when checkbox is selected the whole row should be dark or whatever and when unchecked should go to previous color i.e white
can anyone help? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Angular's [ngStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) and [NgClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) directives can be used for what you're looking for. You'll need to store the state of the checkbox in a variable somewhere that the relevant rows can reach, and then you could do something like this:

```
<some-element [ngClass]="{'class-wanted-when-checked' : checkboxIsChecked}">...</some-element>
```

or this:

```
<some-element [ngStyle]="{'background-color': checkboxIsChecked ? "blue" : "white"}">...</some-element>
```

Comment: what is some-element? @Tyler Church

Comment: `some-element` is just an example element, since I wasn't sure where you'd want the class or style applied. Add [ngClass] or [ngStyle] to whichever element seems most appropriate to you in order to get the appearance that you want.

Comment: i declared a variable checked and equaled it with $event which is true or false 
[ngStyle]="{'background-color': checked == true? 'blue' : 'white'}" like this 
but when i checked the one checkbox it will change the color of every checkboxes even they are not selected

Comment: If you need each checkbox to affect different things, store them in different variables, or give each checkbox an index number or ID and store their checked state in an array or an object.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Tyler but it colors all the rows, for coloring specific rows we need to do the following (Thanks to @Tyler I am using some of his code):

```
        <tr *ngFor="let task of tasks" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': task.complete ? 'lightgreen' : 'white'}">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" (change)="task.complete=!task.complete">
                
            </td>
        </tr>
```

where task.complete is simply a boolean stored as variable.